# How to add timer to other activities when Switch is turned on in the MainActivity?

Tags: android

I'm making a simple word game with different game modes (in different activities), all modes are functional.

But I want to add timer to these game modes when the Switch in the MainActivity (basically consists of buttons that will start different activities when they're clicked) is checked. And when the Switch is toggled off, user can play each game mode without time constraint. How do I implement the timer and Switch function?

Any guidance/hint will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best approach would be using Shared Preferences to store switch values. You can access them anywhere where you have context.

If you don't want to store these values then pass Boolean values in to intent that starts game activity.
Please read:

[Shared Preferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences)

and

[Starting activity with Intent](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity)

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'll try them out :)

Comment: No problem, don't forget to mark it as answered if it will work out for you :)